# Excel Formula - using current formula on second column if first is zero

Tags: microsoft-excel

my formula works on column `H` but now we've added column `I` how do I tell excel to use column `I` if `H` is empty with this formula

```
 =ROUND(IF(H4<=F4*0.03,H4,IF(H4<=F4*0.05,((F4*0.03)+(H4-F4*0.03)*0.5),
(F4*0.03)+((F4*0.02)*0.5))),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=IF(H4<>"",ROUND(IF(H4<=F4*0.03,H4,IF(H4<=F4*0.05,((F4*0.03)+(H4-F4*0.03)*0.5),(F4*0.03)+((F4*0.02)*0.5))),2),ROUND(IF(I4<=F4*0.03,H4,IF(I4<=F4*0.05,((F4*0.03)+(H4-F4*0.03)*0.5),(F4*0.03)+((F4*0.02)*0.5))),2))
```

Comment: Thank you, it's not pulling the data from column "I" still. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.  I did want it to pull from the coloumn if is was zero and not blank.  You were very helpful. this is the formula in working order! Very exciting stuff!
=IF(TRIM(H4)="0",ROUND(IF(I4<=F4*0.03,I4,IF(I4<=F4*0.05,((F4*0.03)+(I4-F4*0.03)*0.5),(F4*0.03)+((F4*0.02)*0.5))),2),ROUND(IF(H4<=F4*0.03,H4,IF(H4<=F4*0.05,((F4*0.03)+(H4-F4*0.03)*0.5),(F4*0.03)+((F4*0.02)*0.5))),2))